# angular ng-href read from scope not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, angularjs-ng-href

here is my downloadable link :
download.xxxxxx.com/yyyyy.json

for company policy reason, I use xxxxxx and yyyyy to illustrate domain and json file name.
but I have tested on my end, this is a downloadable link.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="btn-round btn-primary" ng-href="winlink" value="Download">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.winlink =  'http://download.xxxxxx.com'+ '/' + $scope.name;
```

the problem here is ng-href doesn't work at all. 
When I click the button, nothing happens.